# Referencing Column Titles That Contain Spaces in Python 3 (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Simple question here:  I am trying to reference two columns and then divide them, but the column titles contain spaces.

```
Title 1: First Word Sum
Title 2: First Word Clicks
```

When I try to do something like this, it doesn't work:

```
cvr = (final.First Word Sum / final.First Word Clicks)
```

How do I rectify this?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you are trying to. However the following would work:

```
cvr = final['First Word Sum'] / final['First Word Clicks']
```